# How to add a copy of moderncv footer to an article document class?

Tags: header-footer, moderncv, article

I want to create an article document with a footer like the one in moderncv, see image. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? It doesn't necessarily have to be exactly the same as in moderncv, but something similar.

[image: footer]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant part of code in `moderncv` to create the shown footer is:

```
\renewcommand*{\makeletterfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \addressfont\color{color2}%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}% to cancel out the extra vertical space taken by the name (below) and ensure perfect alignment of letter and cv footers
        \strut{\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\\% the \strut is required to ensure the line is exactly \baselineskip tall
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
```

As you can see the footer is part of the usage of package `fancyhdr`, defined as a centered footer `\fancyfoot[c]{...}`. `\parbox[b]` creates a box, centered `\centering`, with the needed informations for lastname, firstname etc.

So you can create an own footer simplified with:

```
\fancyfoot[c]{%
  \parbox[b]{0.8\textwidth}{%
    \centering%
      \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
      \vspace{-\baselineskip}% to cancel out the extra vertical space taken by the name (below) and ensure perfect alignment of letter and cv footers
      \strut{\bfseries\upshape firstname~lastname}\\% the \strut is required to ensure the line is exactly \baselineskip tall
      street number~city\\
      phone~email~etc.
  }%end parbox
}%end fancyfoot
```

Change firstname etc. to your datas.

This should give you a starting point to do it by your own ...