# Class moderncv, style classic with footer

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

To be honest I have tried a lot to get this working but without any luck. My goal is to add a footer that contains a name on the left side and the page number count on the right side to each site of my cv with class `moderncv`.

For me it is clear how to do that with `moderncv` style `casual` but not with style `classic`.

Has anybody a minimal example that works out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

The desired behavior can be achieved with the following code snippet:

```
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{John Doe}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just got this to work for myself before I found this post. The first problem I found is that the makecvfooter command is not defined for the Classic theme for some reason. The Casual theme does have this defined. You can search the casual theme for the makecvfooter and copy that over, or use this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137403/139573) to a similar question. (I totally suggest referencing that answer.)

After that I made the following changes:

1. Page Numbering

   ```
   % moderncv.cls
   \usepackage{lastpage}% Add this for getting the total page count.

   % moderncvstyleclassic.sty
   \fancyfoot[r]{\thepage of \pageref{LastPage}} % Right side footer area
   ```
2. Centering text. For some reason my contact information was all screwed up. I wanted it page centered and spanning from the center.

   ```
   % Original code
   %\setlength{\footerwidth{0.8\textwidth}} % Definition of footerwidth
   %\parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{% Usage of footerwidth. This should work.

   % My change
   \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{% This got the formatting that I desired for the center.
   ```